# Go to play VS go play

Tags: american-english, british-english, infinitives, imperative-sentences

Please check both sentences and let me know which one is correct.

> You can't just order your children to **go play** while you watch TV.

*vs.*

> You can't just order your children to **go to play** while you watch
>   TV.

Answer (score 5):

"Go play" is a very common turn of phrase. It's often used as a directive, "Go play, I'm busy." It's also perfectly correct and natural in your first example. That sentence sounds just fine.

"Go to play" is stilted sounding, although it may be technically "correct". The only way I can think of that I would use the "to" in that line is if it also included a location. Even then, I have to mess with tenses to make it sound natural. "She went to play in the park."

I could say, "Go play in the park." I might also say, "Let's go to the park to play." I would never say, "Go to play."

Comment: I think "go play" is American. Brits would more likely say "go *and* play in the park".

Comment: Having no experience to the contrary, I'll buy that. :)